# AppWithinMinutes Edit page Error

Tags: xwiki

**Hi I have created an application with AWM.
When I close the "Edit" option in the "Rights" section of the page and click the "Add New Entry" button, I do not switch to the form page and I get "Access denied ...".
On this page, I want to close the option to "edit" the page where the form information is located.
Thanks for your help**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny others to "edit" your application (including its data), you should deny the "edit" right on the **Page and its children** for the individual **Users** or **Groups** that you are interested in. However, make sure you don't deny yourself the edit right, as that is what you seem to be doing by mistake (from what I understand).

Get more info on how the rights work on the documentation pages:

- https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/RightsManagement
- https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/FAQ/HowDoesRightsWork
- https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Access%20Rights/